# is google maps API based on REST?

Tags: api, google-maps, rest, soap

I still don't know if google maps API uses the SOAP protocol or if it's a RESTful service. I've read its documentation but it doesn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but I wanted to try to give an answer anyway, because I do not agree with the logic in @Brick's answer (supports JSON and XML, therefore is RESTful).

There are quite a few [different Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/), so it is hard to answer your question without you specifying which one you mean. However, for an API to be RESTful, it has to comply with the following [five or six constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints):

- Client-Server
- Stateless
- Cacheable
- Layered system
- Code on demand (optional)
- Uniform interface

So an API supporting JSON and XML might, or might not be, RESTful, depending if it complies with the constraints above.

Answer (score 2):

I think Google Maps API is not a REST API.

Google maps API give us tools, methods and objects, when we include its API, We can use these methods to build a map, we need to give data to these objects in order to build our map.

So, we are not really asking for a REST resource, we don't use a REST client to access it and we don't get json or xml data.

A rest API works with standard HTTP methods (like GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE) and returns/add/edit/delete data from its resource.

Answer (score -1):

REST does not enforces message format as XML or JSON or
but it supports both. But SOAP is XML based message protocol it doesnt support JSON.

Since Google Map APIs support both json and xml , it can be safely said they they are implemented in REST.

Further if you look at the URI of google map api , you will see that they are resources based just like REST URI should be ,for example to get the directions resource you hit this URI

```
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```